# Googlemaps with multiple markers and a list of the locations pointing to the markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need a googlemap with clusters, popup and list where you can click on.

Hoping to find a simple solution which I can easily add markers and have a marker list which points to the marker on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully used [markercluster.js](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer)

Just load all your markers into a json (in my example they are in the variable `locations`), then load them:

```
   var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location
      });
      return marker;
    });
```

If you look at the [example code](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/tree/gh-pages/examples), it will show you how easy it is.

Comment: https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/speed_test_example.html

This is perfect! Thank you Fabio

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps JS API documentation is as clear as it comes.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map

I don't think there's an off-the-shelf solution that looks *exactly* like your example. Getting that list is going to require some HTML work to position/render the module, and Javascript/DOM integration to sync it with the map. Some rudimentary front-end development is involved and if that's not something you want to tackle, perhaps you could just make a custom Google Map and link to it.

https://www.google.com/maps/about/mymaps/